# SQL Server Reporting Services - Report Maintenance Tools

Tags: reporting-services, release-management

It seems very easy to deploy new reports to a reporting server directly from visual studio, however when these are to be pushed into our web farm (where developers have no access), this either needs to be done manually, report by report, through microsoft's web front end, or into an MSI.

However, from time to time we might want to reconfigure report options on the report server such as, changing the data source for all reports or changing the caching options for them. Rather than create a whole new MSI for each set of changes or do this manually I wondered if anyone knew of any alternative tools that can update multiple reports at a time or even able to deploy the contents of a folder into a folder on the reporting server.

Cheers, Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Administrators, rs.exe, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162839.aspx , allows remote scripting via VBScript.  If it's possible to give SOAP access, you should be able to accomplish all you want and more without resorting to an MSI.

Thanks, Jamie
Microsoft Reporting Services - Developer

Comment: What if we *want* to use an MSI (or WIX or WebDeploy project) to package up all the reports and data sources into something that can execute at a customer site and accept the needed information in a dialog (SQL and SSRS instance, for example) and then deploy the objects to the SSRS server? Are there any code examples for this?